# Way to convert json output jq

Tags: jq

I have the following json output:

```
[
  {
    "serviceid": "service1",
    "endpoints" : { 
      "endpoint1": [
        "example1",
        "example2",
        "example3",
        "example4"
      ],
      "endpoint2": [
        "example3",
        "example4",
        "example5",
        "example6"
      ]
    },
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  {
    "serviceid": "service2",
    "endpoints" : {
      "endpoint3": [
        "example7",
        "example8",
        "example9",
        "example10"
      ]
    },
    "version": "2.0"
  }
]
```

So I need to remove endpoint1, endpoint2 and endpoint3 and preserve their children as array.
This is the desired output:

```
[
    {
      "serviceid": "service1",
      "endpoints" : [
          "example1",
          "example2",
          "example3",
          "example4"
          "example3",
          "example4",
          "example5",
          "example6"
      ],
      "version": "1.0"
      },
      "serviceid": "service2",
      "endpoints" : [
          "example7",
          "example8",
          "example9",
          "example10"
      ],
      "version": "2.0"
    }
]
```

I don't have any idea to face it, please could you help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've fixed all the typos in your input (several commas and some curly braces were missing), this should work:

```
jq 'map(.endpoints |= [.[][]])'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/dPnG3xSoHW)